# Mongoose remove object from array by date value

Tags: node.js, mongoose, pull

So, I want to remove an object from the array by the date value of the object

Example:

```
[
  {
    first_name: "Support",
    last_name: "Team",
    msg: "Welcome",
    date: "2021-04-26T09:14:53.748+00:00",
  },
];
```

So the above is the structure, and only the date is unique.

Here is what I tried:

```
const { _id, date } = req.body;

Project.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id },
    { $pull: { chat: { date: new Date(date).toISOString() } } },
    { safe: true, multi: true },
    function (err, result) {
      console.log(err);
      if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
      else {
        res.status(200).send("success");
      }
    }
  );
```

Any ideas why it is not deleting the object by the date value?

Answer (score 0):

I had to to wrap date into new Date(date)

Here is the example:

```
Project.findOneAndUpdate(
{ _id },
{ $pull: { chat: { date: new Date(date) } } },
{ safe: true, multi: true },
function (err, result) {
  console.log(err);
  if (err) res.status(500).send(err);
  else {
    res.status(200).send("success");
  }
});
```